# C++ Arrays of Pointers

Tags: c++

I've been tasked to create an array of *pointers* to floats with a typedef.
This is my code:

```
typedef float fArray[3];

fArray fArr[3] = {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}};
fArray* fArrptr[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    fArrptr[i] = &fArr[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  cout << (fArrptr + i) << endl;
}
```

From what I'm understanding it's doing is for fArrptr, it's going through each element of the array and making it point to the 'equivalent element' in fArr. The problem is when I'm trying to output what I'm wanting is 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 but instead, I'm just getting the addresses, regardless of what I do.

Am I misunderstanding what is happening?

Comment: You need to dereference the pointer, it will then 'follow' the pointer and find the floating point (put an asterisk in front, so *(fArrptr+i)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are seriously misunderstanding.

```
typedef float fArray[3];
```

This is typedef for an array of floats, not what you were asked to do, but fine.

```
fArray fArr[3] = {{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}};
```

This is an array of `fArray`. But `fArray` is already an array, so this is an array of an array. A 2D array in other words. That's why you needed to use `{{` when you initialised it.

And similarly this

```
fArray* fArrptr[3];
```

is an array of pointers to an array of floats (not an array of pointers to floats).

After these errors there's not much point going further with the code.

Here's how you create an array of pointers to floats using a typedef

```
typedef float* fPtrArray[3];
fPtrArray array_of_pointers;
```

Here's how you might initialise it

```
float array_of_floats[3] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    array_of_pointers[i] = &array_of_floats[i];
```

And here's how you might print it out

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    cout << *array_of_pointers[i] << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your explanation. I changed it around so I'm doing it properly but in this last bit where I'm printing it out, it's still printing out the addresses instead of the actual float values?

Comment: Have you used my code exactly? I tested it, and it printed numbers for me.

Comment: Tried it with a fresh file and it worked fine thank you. I must've copied something wrong but it's now working perfectly in the bigger program. Thank you heaps!